# How to select multiple column and distinct one column by LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
var names = db.tblPosts.Select(x => new { x.UserID, x.title }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I want select **UserID** and  **title**  and  **UserID** is distinct.

but not worked and userID is not distinct..

Comment: Assuming there are different titles for the same userid, which one would you pick?

Comment: @zerkms , I want select first title

Comment: @Samiey Mehdi: first by what criteria? The shortest one? The one with less vowels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var items = db.tblPosts
              .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
              .Select(g => new { UserId = g.Key, Title = g.FirstOrDefault().Title })
              .ToList();
```

It will return first `Title` for each `UserId`. Add additional `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` to sort items within group before taking first one.

Comment: Is there any way to select all columns? Is there a shortened version to convert the `.ToList()` back to DataTable?

Comment: consider to use First().Title